# Angular Put Method not updating data

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript, mean-stack

i'm newbie with MEAN stack and i have problem when updating data with put Method, i have tested using postman and it works fine, but when i use it on angular its not working. nothing error appear, this what i got in console after updating data
[is give success update][1] but nothing change on data that i updated. i don't have problem with create and delete method, just update method that had problem

here's my code

update.service

```
  updateData(id, data): Observable<any>{
let url = `${this.baseUri}/update/${id}`;
return this.http.put(url,data, { headers : this.headers }).pipe(
  catchError(this.errorManagement)
)}
```

update.component

```
OnSubmit(id){
  let record = this.updateForm.value
  if(!record){
     this.notif.showError('can\'t do update data','Update data Error')
     return false;
}else{
    return this.motorService.updateData(id, record).subscribe(res=>{
    console.log(record)
  },(error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });
}}}
```

update route

```
listDataRoute.route('/update/:id').put((req,res,next)=>{
    listData.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{
        $set : req.body
    },{new: true, useFindAndModify: false},(error, data)=>{
         if (data.n > 0) {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: 'profile updated'
        });
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({
          message: 'not authorized'
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: 'updating profile failed'
      });
    })
})
```

any idea what i do wrong ? i'm already stuck like 5 hours with this error, thank you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryR8g.png

update : i got error 401 after adding some code in "update route", still don't know how to solve this error

Comment: did you compare if you arent missing any properties on the object you want to update. i was missing some properties in my backnd controller function when i had the same problem as you

Comment: thx for the comment, can u explain it about what properties are missing ? i am so confuse @Fiehra

Comment: i was sending an update where i update my age for example. but my backend controller was not handling the age property. so thats why the update was successfull but my age never changed. i posted my code how i handled update calls   hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

id like to share my way of updating data with the mean stack. its a lil different from your code but it works and is tested with jest. id like to share my example with updating a userprofile

i create a userModel in my backend user.js

```
// user.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    currentLocation: String,
    age: String,
  });

  userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
 
  module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

then i write the update method in my profileController.js

```
// profileController.js
exports.update = (req, res, next) => {
  const user = new User({
    _id: req.body.id,
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    currentLocation: req.body.currentLocation,
    age: req.body.age,
  });
  User.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, user).then(result => {
      if (result.n > 0) {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: 'profile updated'
        });
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({
          message: 'not authorized'
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: 'updating profile failed'
      });
    });
}
```

in my profilerService.ts (frontend) i also define my userclass with the same properties as the user.js model in my backend

```
// profile.service.ts
export class User {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  currentLocation: string;
  age: string;

  constructor() {
    this.id = '';
    this.email = '';
    this.username = '';
    this.password = '';
    this.currentLocation = '';
    this.age = '';
  }
}
```

i also add the update service call into my service file

```
// profile.service.ts
updateProfile(user: User, userId: string) {
    return this.http.put(environment.backendUrl + '/api/user/' + userId, user);
  }
```

then i can call the service function from my component where i want to update my user

```
  // profile-page.component.ts
  updateProfile(user: User) {
    this.profileService.updateProfile(user, user.id).subscribe(response => {
      console.log('update successfull');
    });
  }
```

i hope my code snippets are able to help you! let me know if anything still needs some clarification. sry if this isnt the most perfect answer as this is one of my first answers on SO :)

Comment: after i tried your code especialy in profileController.js, i got 401 error, do you have some advice about that error ? thx

Comment: did you make sure you are passing in the correct id? 401 looks like the User.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, user).then function was unsuccessful.
you could also check if your url is correct and if it matches with the backend url

Comment: i just check my update url using postman and it's working, still don''t know what i do wrong

Answer (score 0):

401 means **Authentication** error.

Is post working?

Comment: thx for the answere, my application doesnt use any login user or authentication, that's why i dont know how to solve this error, do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: can you check your browser console, any CORS error?

Also, can you check Mongoose is connecting successfully to Mongo DB?
It seems mongoose is failing.

Comment: i got nothing error except 401 error,and my connection to mongodb is working just fine, do you have any clue ? @Rajdeep Debnath

Comment: You are getting 401 and nothing else because at node.js side you are setting only that much. 

Can you console.log(data) and console.log(error) both at Node.js server side?